# [Xcode]Add 3rd party library to custom framework project

Tags: xcode

I make the framework project.
I used 'Alamofire' library while make the project.

But When I junctioning(?) the this framework to the project.
error occured in my framework!(not in the project.)

there is no such module error.

'Alamofire' is using my project too.

I want to know how to set framework with 3rd party library.(i tried to make the pod file then it also same..)

Can you give me any tutorial?